# Expected initializer before function

Tags: c++, fortran, g++

I have a solver in Fortran. And my main file is in C++. I am including the solver header file in the main file to call solver function which is in Fortran. 
But I am getting the following error while compiling the code.

```
In file included from eph.cpp:12:0:
eph.cpp: At global scope:
radau.h:48:29: error: expected initializer before ‘radau_’
  #define RADAU FORTRAN_NAME(radau)
                             ^
radau.h:36:25: note: in definition of macro ‘FORTRAN_NAME’
 #define FORTRAN_NAME(x) x ## _
                         ^
eph.cpp:225:17: note: in expansion of macro ‘RADAU’
  void __stdcall RADAU(int *n,void *Function,double *x,double *y,double *xend,d
```

I am attaching the main .cpp file and the header file for reference.

eph.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iomanip>
//#include <fortran.h>
//#include "StiffIntegratorT.h"
//#include "NonStiffIntegratorT.h"
#include "forceModelsHPOP.h";
extern "C"{
#include "radau.h";
}

using namespace std;

//inline void Function( double x, double y[][1],double y0[][1]);
//inline void Jacobian(double x, double *y, double **J);
//inline void Mass(double **M);

/*---------------------------------Main Accel---------------------------------------------*/

void Function(int *n,double *var,double *y,double *f,double *rpar,int *ipar)
{
    double Mjd_UTC = 51543.9583333335;
    double A = 29.0;
    double M = 1005.0;
    double Cr = 1.0;
//  double *secs = 86400.0;
    double x; 
    var = &x;
    double MJD_UTC;
    MJD_UTC = Mjd_UTC+x/86400.0; 

    double UT1_TAI,UTC_GPS,UT1_GPS,TT_UTC,GPS_UTC;
    double xp,yp,UT1_UTC,lod,dpsi,deps,dxp,dyp,TAI_UTC;
    IERS(xp,yp,UT1_UTC,lod,dpsi,deps,dxp,dyp,TAI_UTC,MJD_UTC,'l');
    timediff(UT1_TAI,UTC_GPS,UT1_GPS,TT_UTC,GPS_UTC,UT1_UTC,TAI_UTC);

    double year, month, day, hour, minute, sec;
    double DJMJD0, DATE;
    double JD = MJD_UTC+2400000.5;
    invjday(year, month, day, hour, minute, sec,JD);
    iauCal2jd(DJMJD0, DATE,year, month, day);

    double TIME = (60*(60*hour + minute) + sec)/86400;
    double UTC = DATE + TIME;
    double TT = UTC + TT_UTC/86400;
    double TUT = TIME + UT1_UTC/86400;
    double UT1 = DATE + TUT;

    double Pi[3][3],NPB[3][3];
    double sp, gast;
    sp = iauSp00(DJMJD0, TT);
    iauPom00(Pi,xp, yp,sp);
    iauPnm06a(NPB,DJMJD0, TT);
    gast = iauGst06(DJMJD0, UT1, DJMJD0, TT, NPB);

    double eye[3][3] = {{1,0,0},{0,1,0},{0,0,1}};
    double Theta[3][3];
    iauRz(gast, eye);

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            Theta[i][j] = eye[i][j];
//          cout << Theta[i][j] << endl;
        }
    }

    double res1[3][3],E[3][3];
    multiplyMat(Theta,NPB,res1);
    multiplyMat(Pi,res1,E);

    double MJD_TDB;
    double r_Mercury[3], r_Venus[3], r_Earth[3], r_Mars[3], r_Jupiter[3], r_Saturn[3], r_Uranus[3], \
                    r_Neptune[3], r_Pluto[3], r_Moon[3], r_Sun[3], r_SunSSB[3];
    MJD_TDB = Mjday_TDB(TT);

    JPL_Eph_DE436(r_Mercury, r_Venus, r_Earth, r_Mars, r_Jupiter, r_Saturn, r_Uranus, \
                            r_Neptune, r_Pluto, r_Moon, r_Sun, r_SunSSB, MJD_TDB);

    static double r_Sun1[3][1],r_Moon1[3][1],r_Earth1[3][1];
    static double r_Mercury1[3][1],r_Venus1[3][1],r_Mars1[3][1],r_Jupiter1[3][1],r_Saturn1[3][1],r_Uranus1[3][1], \
                    r_Neptune1[3][1],r_Pluto1[3][1],r_SunSSB1[3][1];
    static double VecInPos[3][1],VecInVel[3][1];

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        r_Sun1[i][0] = r_Sun[i];
        r_Moon1[i][0] = r_Moon[i];
        r_Mercury1[i][0] = r_Mercury[i];
        r_Venus1[i][0] = r_Venus[i];
        r_Mars1[i][0] = r_Mars[i];
        r_Jupiter1[i][0] = r_Jupiter[i];
        r_Saturn1[i][0] = r_Saturn[i];
        r_Uranus1[i][0] = r_Uranus[i];
        r_Neptune1[i][0] = r_Neptune[i];
        r_Pluto1[i][0] = r_Pluto[i];
        r_Earth1[i][0] = r_Earth[i];
        r_SunSSB1[i][0] = r_SunSSB[i];
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        VecInPos[i][0] = y[i];
        VecInVel[i][0] = y[i+3];
//      cout << VecInPos[i][0] << endl;
    }

    static double aG[3][1],aSol[3][1],asRad[3][1],aRel[3][1],a[3][1];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
//      cout << setprecision(11) << r_Sun1[i][0] << endl;
    }

    AccelHarmonic_ElasticEarth(aG, MJD_UTC, r_Sun1, r_Moon1, VecInPos, E, UT1_UTC, TT_UTC, xp, yp);
//  cout << aG[0][0] << endl;

    static double a1[3][1], a2[3][1], a3[3][1], a4[3][1], a5[3][1], a6[3][1], a7[3][1], a8[3][1], a9[3][1], a10[3][1];
    static double aS[3][1], aM[3][1], aMe[3][1], aV[3][1], aMa[3][1], aJ[3][1], aSa[3][1], aU[3][1], aN[3][1], aP[3][1];

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
//      cout << setprecision(11) << GM_Sun << endl;
    }

    AccelPointMass(a1,VecInPos,r_Sun1,GM_Sun);
    AccelPointMass(a2,VecInPos,r_Moon1,GM_Moon);
    AccelPointMass(a3,VecInPos,r_Mercury1,GM_Mercury);
    AccelPointMass(a4,VecInPos,r_Venus1,GM_Venus);
    AccelPointMass(a5,VecInPos,r_Mars1,GM_Mars);
    AccelPointMass(a6,VecInPos,r_Jupiter1,GM_Jupiter);
    AccelPointMass(a7,VecInPos,r_Saturn1,GM_Saturn);
    AccelPointMass(a8,VecInPos,r_Uranus1,GM_Uranus);
    AccelPointMass(a9,VecInPos,r_Neptune1,GM_Neptune);
    AccelPointMass(a10,VecInPos,r_Pluto1,GM_Pluto);

    AccelSolrad(aSol, VecInPos, r_Earth1, r_Moon1, r_Sun1, r_SunSSB1, A, M, Cr, P_Sol, AU, "cylindrical");

    Relativity(aRel, VecInPos, VecInVel);

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        aS[i][0] = aG[i][0] + a1[i][0];
        aM[i][0] = aS[i][0] + a2[i][0];
        aMe[i][0] = aM[i][0] + a3[i][0];
        aV[i][0] = aMe[i][0] + a4[i][0];
        aMa[i][0] = aV[i][0] + a5[i][0];
        aJ[i][0] = aMa[i][0] + a6[i][0];
        aSa[i][0] = aJ[i][0] + a7[i][0];
        aU[i][0] = aSa[i][0] + a8[i][0];
        aN[i][0] = aU[i][0] + a9[i][0];
        aP[i][0] = aN[i][0] + a10[i][0];
        asRad[i][0] = aP[i][0] + aSol[i][0];
        a[i][0] = asRad[i][0] + aRel[i][0];
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        f[i] = VecInVel[i][0];
        f[i+3] = a[i][0];
//      cout << f[i+3] << endl;
    }

    cout << "y0 " << f[0] << endl;
//}
    return;
//  cout << xp << endl;
}

void Jacobian(int *n, double *x, double *y, double *dfy,
           int *ldfy, double *rpar, double *ipar)
{
    return;
}

void Mass(int *n,double *am, int *lmas,int *rpar, int *ipar)
{
    return;
}

void solout(int *nr,double *xold,double *x,
            double *y,
            double *cont,int *lrc,
            int *n,
            double *rpar,int *ipar,
            int *irtrn)
{
//  printf("Step %3i: t=%1.3e, y=(%1.3e,%1.3e)\n",*nr, *x,y[0],y[1]);
//  cout << "Step \t:" << *nr << "t= " << *x << "y = " << "(" << y[0] << ", " << y[1] << ")" << endl;
    return;
}

extern "C"
{
    void __stdcall RADAU(int *n,void *Function,double *x,double *y,double *xend,double *h, \
        double *rtol,double *atol,int *itol, \
        void *Jacobian,int *ijac,int *mljac,int *mujac, \
        void *Mass,int *imas,int *mlmas,int *mumas, \
        void *solout,int *iout, \
                double *work,double *lwork,double *iwork,double *liwork,double *rpar,int *ipar,int *idid);
}

int main()
{

#define ND     6
#define NS     7
#define LWORK  (NS+1)*ND*ND+(3*NS+3)*ND+20
#define LIWORK (2+(NS-1)/2)*ND+20

    double y[ND],work[LWORK];
    int iwork[LIWORK];
    double x,xend;
    int i,idid;

    /*(no) parameter in the differential equation*/
    double   rpar=0;
    /*dimension of the system*/
    int  n=6;
    /* compute the jacobian analytically */
    int ijac=0;
    /* jacobian is a full matrix*/
    int mljac=n;
    int mujac=0;
    /* differential equation is in explicit form*/
    int imas=0;
    int mlmas=0;
    int mumas;
    int ipar=0;
    /* output routine is used during integration*/
    int iout=0;

    /* required tolerance*/
    double rtol=1.0e-2;
    double atol=1.0e-6*rtol;
    int itol=0;
    /* initial step size*/
    double h=1.0e-6;

    int lwork=LWORK;
    int liwork=LIWORK;

    /* initial values*/
    x=0.0;
    y[0]=-23788115.6646;
    y[1]=34839281.8482;
    y[2]=-14387.644;
    y[3]=-2537.92541;
    y[4]=-1732.91352;
    y[5]=0.87796;

    /* endpoint of integration*/
    xend=1.0;
    /* set default values */
    for(i=0; i<20; i++){
        iwork[i]=0;
        work[i]=0.0;
    }

//  printf("\n**********\n* radau  *\n**********\n\n");

    RADAU(&n,Function,&x,y,&xend,&h,
        &rtol,&atol,&itol,
        Jacobian,&ijac,&mljac,&mujac,
        Mass,&imas,&mlmas,&mumas,
        solout,&iout,
        work,&lwork,iwork,&liwork,&rpar,&ipar,&idid);

    return (0);
}
```

header: radau.h

```
#ifndef RADAU_H
#define RADAU_H

#ifdef CPP
extern C {
#endif

//#define INTEL_FORTRAN
/*#define IRIX*/                   /* MipsPro Compiler */
//#define SOLARIS                /* Sun Workshop Compiler */
#define Gplusplus                   

/* without underscore, upper case*/
#ifdef INTEL_FORTRAN
#define UPPERCASE
#define FORTRAN_NAME(x) x
#endif

/* with underscore, lower case*/
#ifdef IRIX  
#define FORTRAN_NAME(x) x ## _
#endif

/* with underscore, lower case*/
#ifdef SOLARIS  
#define FORTRAN_NAME(x) x ## _
#endif

/* with underscore, lower case*/
#ifdef Gplusplus
#define LOWERCASE
#define FORTRAN_NAME(x) x ## _
#endif


#ifdef UPPERCASE
#define RADAU FORTRAN_NAME(RADAU)
#define RADAU5 FORTRAN_NAME(RADAU5) 
#define CONTRA FORTRAN_NAME(CONTRA) 
#define CONTR5 FORTRAN_NAME(CONTR5)
#endif
#ifdef LOWERCASE
//#define RADAU FORTRAN_NAME(radau)
    #define RADAU FORTRAN_NAME(radau)
//#define RADAU5 FORTRAN_NAME(radau5)
//#define CONTRA FORTRAN_NAME(contra) 
//#define CONTR5 FORTRAN_NAME(contr5) 

#endif
```

The solver defn is in the next line of header file.

Comment: wow 26 argument for one function how are you suppose to works with that

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] with all dependencies?

Comment: An example containing just the FORTRAN_NAME and RADAU define and invokation works just fine. So somewhere between that and your full code is the error. Remove chunks from your code till the error goes away and you will find the actual culprid.

Comment: I found the problem. In my headerfile already the whole code was wrapped inside extern C. But I was again declaring the function inside extern C in my main function. Thank You for help.